# how to display image from documents folder in of iphone to image ViewI

Tags: iphone, ios, imageview, documents

I want to display image saved in the documents folder problem is that it returns file name but it does not show image in the image View

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
            NSString*patientlastName;    

            NSString*test=@"nicej";

           patientlastName=[test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        NSString * filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents//%@.png", NSHomeDirectory(),patientlastName];


        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
        if (fileExists == 0) 
        { 
            NSLog(@"File is Not exists");

            appDelegate.imageURL=@"File Not Exists";

        }

        NSString *userfile=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",patientlastName];
        appDelegate.imageURL=userfile;

           PictureDisplayViewController *targetController = [[PictureDisplayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PictureDisplayViewController" bundle:nil];
        targetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        [self.splitViewController presentViewController:targetController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In PictureDisplayViewController

```
           imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"nicej.png"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

**save image in this path**:

```
 NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",patientlastName];
   NSString *Image_filePath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
 NSData *imagedata=UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourimage);
 [fileMan createFileAtPath:[Image_filePath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] contents:imagedata attributes:nil];
```

**get image path**:

```
NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",patientlastName}
        NSArray *arrayPaths =
        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                            NSDocumentDirectory,
                                            NSUserDomainMask,
                                            YES);
        NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

      UIImage *image1=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
       imageView.image=image1;
```

Comment: this also not showing image in imageView

Comment: i am saving file as you have given but it does not load what may be the problem

Comment: can you please help me out in this http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/pro/j.png

Comment: i want that in new NSString instead of showing this whole url i want to get j.png only in other NSString

Comment: leave url i am asking that if i haie celeritas.com/test.png i want test.png in other variable how to get this

Comment: NSString *str1=[[urlstring componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]lastObject];

Comment: code for image showing is working when i place image in documents folder but it does not get from device which i save

Comment: i have problem i want to ask that the video or image i save in documents folder then i upload that to server when i check that again then it shows nothing in the app

Comment: if you are saving image into Document directory then how to show this image in to device gallery...?

Answer (score 0):

```
//suppose  imgpath is path of your image in doument directory then use these two lines of code.

NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];

imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
```

Answer (score 0):

In `PictureDisplayViewController`, you are loading image with `imageNamed` method that actually doesn't work until you have image with the same name into your bundle.
you can load image like as follow...

In `PictureDisplayViewController` you already have path for the image than

```
imageView.image=  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePathWithName];
```

Comment: i have done like kirthi in PictureDisplayViewController but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I modify your code :

```
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
                NSString*patientlastName;    

                NSString*test=@"nicej";

               patientlastName=[test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
            NSString * filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents//%@.png", NSHomeDirectory(),patientlastName];


            BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
            if (fileExists == 0) 
            { 
                NSLog(@"File is Not exists");

                appDelegate.imagePath=@"";

            }
            else
            {
                appDelegate.imagePath=filePath;
            }

               PictureDisplayViewController *targetController = [[PictureDisplayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PictureDisplayViewController" bundle:nil];
            targetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
            [self.splitViewController presentViewController:targetController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In PictureDisplayViewController

```
if(appDelegate.imagePath)
{
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:appDelegate.imagePath];
}
else
{
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];
}
```

`default.png` is a default png pic in your bundle resource

Comment: i am doing like the edited code direct in PicDisplayViewController but it still does not show image

Comment: Please make sure :is there a png in your `filePath`? The `fileExists` is `YES` or `NO`?

Comment: it shows No file but i am saving file