# Display image from path in imageView in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I have image path and I want to display it in uiimageview,

> /Users/WTS-New/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F43C‌​26D2-DCFF-4764-AAF0-‌​F6CC7BCDCF5D/data/Co‌​ntainers/Data/Applic‌​ation/8E49D340-7CAC-‌​4031-85BF-9E5C26A1E3‌​7A/Documents/Small-m‌​ario.png

How can I get image to displayed?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916753/how-to-display-image-from-documents-folder-in-of-iphone-to-image-viewi

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005381/get-image-from-documents-directory-swift

Comment: Solution ->> http://stackoverflow.com/a/8636045/4970453

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using below code:

***Get image path from Image name:***

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imageFilePath;
NSError *err;

imageFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Small-m‌​ario.png"];
```

***Set image using `imageWithContentsOfFile` method:***

```
YourImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imageFilePath];
```

Answer (score 2):

**To display image from complete file path on device**

```
NSString *path = @"<your file path>;
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

**The key is using `fileURLWithPath` instead of `URLWithString` when converting to `NSURL`*

Comment: the question is laod image from local path not a server , at the same time question is tagged in objective C, can you modify your answer

Comment: `fileURLWithPath` is actually a valid solution for this. It will load the file from local path.

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.