# Why is NSFileManager unable to find these png files?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nsfilemanager

I have written code to open image files after studying answers to the questions found here ([a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8635909/2348597), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17916753/2348597), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39248865/2348597), [d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636045/2348597), [e](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8635946/2348597), [f](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6663576/2348597) & [g](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6663685/2348597)). But NSFileManager is unable to find them even though I added the png files to the project. I'm reasonably confident my code should be able to recognise either of the png files if they were in the right directory.

```
e.g.

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

    NSArray  *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;
    
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    
    NSLog(@"\ndirPaths %@ \n\ndocsDir \n%@", dirPaths, docsDir);
    
    NSString *imageFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iTunesArtwork1024.png"];
    
    NSLog(@"\n\nfile path should be \n\n%@ \n\n", imageFilePath);
    
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath];
    
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:imageFilePath])
    
    {
        NSLog(@"\nFound file path : %@", imageFilePath);
    }
    
    else
    
    {
        NSLog(@"\nImage file not found");
    }

    UIImage  *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    
    UIImageView *logo = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    logo.image = image;
    [self.view addSubview:logo];

}
```

But here is the log in the debug window

```
    2017-07-14 18:26:35.679 IconShape[1089:348564] 
    dirPaths (
    "/Users/gs/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57279C80-0937-4658-B0E6-7984B3768D56/data/Containers/Data/Application/18235DBF-7ADB-47D4-AFF9-282D02F2A0F8/Documents"
    ) 

    docsDir 
    /Users/gs/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57279C80-0937-4658-B0E6-7984B3768D56/data/Containers/Data/Application/18235DBF-7ADB-47D4-AFF9-282D02F2A0F8/Documents
    2017-07-14 18:26:35.679 IconShape[1089:348564] 

    file path should be 

    /Users/gs/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57279C80-0937-4658-B0E6-7984B3768D56/data/Containers/Data/Application/18235DBF-7ADB-47D4-AFF9-282D02F2A0F8/Documents/iTunesArtwork1024.png 

    2017-07-14 18:26:35.679 IconShape[1089:348564] 
    Image file not found
```

Here is the state of the project after two png files were added.
[image]
Yet the log shows they are not visible to NSFileManager. So where would they be found ? i.e. what changes do I need to make to my code in order to find them ?

---

EDIT

This draft finds the png file following Subramanian's recommendation.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSFileManager *fileManager  = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

    NSString *imageFilePath     = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"iTunesArtwork1024" ofType:@"png"];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:imageFilePath])

    {
        NSLog(@"\nFound file path : %@", imageFilePath);
    }

    else

    {
        NSLog(@"\nImage file not found");
    }

    UIImage  *image     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iTunesArtwork1024.png"];
    UIImageView *logo   = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)];
    logo.image          = image;
    [self.view addSubview:logo];
}
```

The log now reads

```
     Found file path :  … .app/iTunesArtwork1024.png
```

and the image also appears in the `subview.`

__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Image is not in the`Document Directory`, It's inside the `bundle`.**

You have added the image files inside the project. But You are checking the image on `Document` Directory, Which is wrong. Image is inside `app bundle`.

**You can simply assign the `Image` to `UIImageView` by the `name` of the image.**

```
UIImage  *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iTunesArtwork1024.png"];

UIImageView *logo = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
logo.image = image;
```

If you want to get the path of the image, then you have to use `[NSBundle mainBundle]`

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"iTunesArtwork1024" ofType:@"png"];
```

Comment: Subramanian, progress. iTunesArtwork1024.png appears in the directory but the image still doesn't display. See my edit

Comment: Subramanian, you've explained and solved my problem. Much appreciated. This has to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

**You can access images with names which are added in projects. Try with below code**

```
 UIImage  *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iTunesArtwork1024.png"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The path where your are looking for the image is inside your device (real or simulator).

To load an image that is stored in your XCode project just do:

`UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iTunesArtwork1024.png"];`